# Joomla - Clear definition of JTable and JModelBase class?

Tags: joomla3.2

I am making a Joomla 3.2 component by following the [Lendr](http://lendr.websparkinc.com/) tutorial. They seem to add all of the database columns to their [model](https://github.com/sparkbuilt/lendr/blob/master/com_lendr/site/models/book.php) as protected fields (use helper get/set functions to manipulate them) and CRUD operations as functions. Their table class only contains a constructor:

```
  function __construct( &$db ) {
    parent::__construct('#__lendr_books', 'book_id', $db);
  }
```

When they are getting or saving an item, they return an instance of their table class rather than an updated version of the model e.g. if you saved a new item, the protected ID field on the model would be zero, but the ID on the returned table object would be non-zero.

So to me, it doesn't make sense to put all of the columns on the model and it would be better to explicitly declare them on the table class, or keep them updated on the model and don't return any table objects.

Components built into Joomla aren't using the new MVC convention and seem to be all over the show with where to but the CRUD operations.

Is there a clear definition of what the Model should do and what the Table should do in Joomla 3.2 using the non-legacy MVC classes?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be like this:

**[JTable](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JTable.html)** Seems to be similar to Ruby on Rails' `ActiveRecord::Base`. It models the database and there is not really a need to put anything extra in here besides a constructor which declares the table name and primary key and possibly override some methods e.g. [check](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JTable.html#method_check). Basic CRUD operations are provided by `JTable` which will usually be called by your class that extends `JModelBase`.

```
  function __construct( &$db ) {
    parent::__construct('#__my_table', 'id', $db);
  }
```

**[JModelBase](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JModelBase.html)** handles the business logic of your model as well as preparing queries (which will often return the corresponding `JTable` values. The controller should always deal directly with this and not `JTable`.

In both cases there is not a need to explicitly add the database columns as properties on the class (just like in Rails).